# toArray() vs. toArray(new Object[0])

Tags: java, type-conversion, toarray

I have an `ArrayList<Clause>` called `listtable`. For some reason `Clause[] whatever = listtable.toArray()` gives an incompatible types error but `Clause[] whatever = listtable.toArray(new Clause[0])` works just fine. Why is this so? What is the difference between the two calls? The javadoc says they are "identical in function".

Here is my full code (the relevant statement is right before the end):

```
public static Clause[] readCNF(String name,Boolean print) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./" + name));

        ArrayList<Clause> listtable = new ArrayList<Clause>();
        String line = null; 
        while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {

            if(line.charAt(0) == 'p')
            {
                 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line); 
                 scanner.next(); scanner.next(); Clause.NumVars = scanner.nextInt(); Clause.NumClauses = scanner.nextInt(); 

            } else if(line.charAt(0) != 'c') {  

                 ArrayList<Integer> lits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);

                 while(scanner.hasNext())
                 {
                     int var = scanner.nextInt();
                     if(var != 0){ lits.add(var);}
                 }

                 listtable.add(new Clause(lits));

            } 
        }

        if(print) {
            for(Clause clause : listtable)
            {
                clause.print();
            }
        }

       return(listtable.toArray(new Clause[0])); //since the return type is Clause[] this is the same as the statements in the question
    }
```

Comment: Continue reading the javadoc: _the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array._

Comment: Still, why would they have a toArray() method if it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean _it doesn't work_? Did you put a cast? Is that a safe cast? What is the return type specified by the javadoc? It works very well and as intended.

Comment: I mean it doesn't compile without the new Object[0] inside the parentheses

Comment: The javadoc very clearly states that the return type of the method is `Object[]`. So assign it to an `Object[]`.

Comment: So what is the use of .toArray()? Without anything inside.

Comment: Shorthand, possibly, or legacy compatibility.

Comment: I believe it came before generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toArray()` returns an array of `Object`. You have to cast every element of the array to your desired type.

The `toArray(T[])` accepts a generic type and returns an array of the specific type. No need to cast the return value and/or the elements of the array.

As stated in the comments above, the `toArray()` method came pre-generics.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Alice");
    list.add("Bob");

    String[] strArray = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (String str : strArray) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    Object[] objArray = list.toArray();
    for (Object obj : objArray) {
        String str = (String) obj;
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```